# Tracking clicks on link you do not own

Tags: analytics

Is there any way to look at a random link on the internet and find out how many times it has been clicked if the link is not on my website and does not point to my website?

For example, the link `www.reddit.com/aRandomUniqueQueryParameter` is on the site `www.iDontOwnThis.com`. How can I determine how many times the Reddit link has been clicked from `iDontOwnThis.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, but the owner of the **`www.iDontOwnThis.com`** can check it out in Analytics/Statistics of his site. Also, the owner of **`www.reddit.com`** is able to see the same stats. These stats are private due to security issues so you as a 3rd-party public viewer won't be able to get those numbers.

However, if you have access to the post you could wrap the link into **https://bitly.com/** and peek on clicks.

Comment: That bit.ly trick is not a useful statistic. Only a very limited subset of visitors to the page would use it.